# MSProject Add-In doesn't include nuget reference packages during publishing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vsto, ms-project

I have a VSTO add-in for MS Project. When I build the project, all the required dll's are in a bin folder. But when I perform publish, the dll's, which comes from nuget, is missing in publish directory. It happens only if I use Visual Studio 2017. Publish trough VS 2019 works fine, but I cannot change the VS version right now. I see, that the problem related to manifest. But it generates automatically.
Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Are you nuget dependencies listed in `packages.config` file or as `PackageReferences` inside of `*.csproj` file?

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich sure. as workaround I copy a missing dll's directly from a nuget cache during publishing.

Comment: I remember a very similar issue after I added .NET Standard library to the solution. For some reasons after I referenced this library in VSTO project I didn't get all the Nuget dependencies in the `bin` folder. Solution was to migrate the VSTO project from using the `packages.config` to using of `PackageReferences` records in the `*.csproj` file.

Comment: But it seems that's a different issue because I was missing dependent NuGet dlls as the result of the build, not publish.

Comment: @AlexeyAndrushkevich thanks for the answer. I already use PackageReferences. I see only two solutions for now, either the described  workaround with dll's copy, or migrate to VS 2019 because it looks like a bug in 2017 version.